# How to make a 1x city bike easier to ride uphill?

Tags: chainring, hills

I'm trying to convert an old city bike (https://archive.trekbikes.com/us/en/2010/trek/navigator10wsd#/us/en/2010/trek/navigator10wsd/details) for my middle-aged mother who did not do any sports so far. There are a lot of slopes in our town, so I want the gear ratio to be as "easy" as possible.

As you can see in the link, the bike has a 1x 42t front chainring and the cassette goes up to 34t.

How would you do it? The following is what I think:

I believe 34t is ok, but 42t is too much. I looked for other 1x systems but no one sells a 1x chainring with 22t or 24t.

Then I decided to buy a 2x or 3x system with a smallest chainring of 22 or 24t and fixing it to that lowest chainring using a front derailleur and limit screws. (You may ask why am I not installing a full 2x/3x system with gear levers and cables: I really do not think she will need the bigger chainring, and there is no routing for the front derailleur cable. If she starts to ride a lot and needs that second chainring I may think about it.)

Do you see any problem with my solution?
To avoid the chain being not linear when the smallest ring is used in the cassette, is it better to buy a 2x system? (Is smallest chainring of the 2x systems are closer to the right side, compared to 3x systems? I guess that would help to keep the chain linear.)

Comment: You might get more buy-in by retrofitting an electric assistance motor.  Climbing is hard - she may choose to ride around hills rather than over.

Comment: Bear in mind that with a sufficiently low gear, it can be hard to maintain enough forward momentum to keep the bike upright. This will be determined somewhat by the rider's bike-handling skill, but my guess is that anything below a 1:1 ratio (eg 34x34) may be hard to keep upright.

Comment: Do you really think that single speed is a good idea for an unfit person in a hilly area? A 1:1 ratio would mean a speed between 9km/h (at 70rpm) and 13km/h (100 rpm cadence). Too strenuous for uphill (like ≥7% gradients) while barely faster than a brisk walk in flat terrain. Get her some gears. A fixed gear bicycle is really only a good idea for flat terrain and/or fit cyclists who can output a lot of power for  acceleration or short uphill sections.

Comment: nobody suggested e-bike (adding battery and motor) yet?

Comment: @Michael It is a 1x, not a single speed.

Comment: @Jakuje Would be cheaper to just buy a new bike I think.

Comment: @Jakuje The first comment was about adding a motor

Comment: Lot's of people are suggesting some sort of electrical assist. A front electrical wheel will set OP back over $300. For that price, OP could get a used 2x or 3x bike off craigslist.

Comment: @sam One could get a used 2x or 3x off craiglist, but can one find *that* bicycle with a 2x or 3x off craiglist? I think the goal is improving an existing bike for a casual rider, who is enjoying the current bike fit. Changing the bike is an option? I don't think so ...

Comment: @AdamRice many MTBs are geared well below 1:1, e.g. I've got 22:32 on mine (with a triple).   On the rare occasions I've used that gear up steep but smooth stuff, handling hasn't been a problem.  Lifting the front wheel is another matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with installing a 3x crankset on the bike, and having her only use the smallest chainring. Some benefits of this solution:

- This is the cheapest and easiest solution.
- If the smallest chainring has 22 teeth, her lowest gear ratio will be 22/34, which will make climbing hills very easy.
- If the smallest chainring is too easy, you can simply move the chain up to the middle chainring, which will probably have 32 or 34 teeth.
- You will not need to install a front derailleur.
- Using the smallest chainring and the smallest sprocket (aka having a crooked or non-linear chainline) is not a major problem on modern bikes, as you suggest it might be.

Comment: I like this no-frill solution. Additoinally, with(out using) the largest ring, there is a lot of room to fiddle with adding a chain guard / chain cover, which would be a sure welcome for the intended use of the bike.

Answer (score 8):

I'm a big fan of low gears (I run a 22 inner ring on my MTB despite being a fairly strong climber), but I'd say a 22 or 24t ring is too small to use as an only ring - it'll spin out much to easily on slight downhills or with tailwinds.

You can get 1x cranks for MTB that come as standard with a 30T ring, and aftermarket 28T rings - I'd suggest these would be a better compromise.

As another alternative, if you are doing a conversion anyway, perhaps you might like to consider an aftermarket e-bike conversion?

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest you go with an IGH (internal geared hub), a 29T front chainring and a 24T on the back.

It works, the only caution needed is that shifting while pedaling hard should be avoided, otherwise the internal of the IGH will wear out quickly ... I don't think this will be an issue for your low-power mother.

Comment: That upgrade would cost much more than the bike is worth.

Comment: @mattnz how much is the proper bike fitting worth to the OP's relative? sometimes it has an infinite value: a comfortable bike will be ridden, an uncomfortable one will sit in the garage unused :)